# How does position of break; is making a difference in output?

Tags: java

I was working upon a program when i noticed something weird in its output behaviour :

Getting required output :

```
while ((str = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
      if(str.contains("sometext"))
      {
         while(str.contains("some_diff_text")==false)
         {
           if(str.contains("something"))
             break;
           else
           {
             //my code;
           }
        }
        break;                     //difference in output because of this break position
      }
    }
```

Not Getting required output :

```
while ((str = input.readLine()) != null)
{
          if(str.contains("sometext"))
          {
             while(str.contains("some_diff_text")==false)
             {
               if(str.contains("something"))
                 break;
               else
               {
                 //my code;
               }
            }

          }
          break;                     //not giving me the required output
    }
```

**Can someone explain me why there is a difference in the output behaviour ?**

Comment: first break break inner while, and the second one breaks outter while
but in 1st example u break outter while only on if statment

Comment: What is this? You tagged it with four different programming languages.

Comment: Don't put irrelevant tags on your questions. As well as being obnoxious, it makes it harder for people to tell what language you're using, so it's harder for them to help you.

Comment: i tagged it with different language tags because break statement is used in all of these

Comment: Then tag it with `break`. If you're not actually using a language, don't put the language tag on your question.

Comment: This is a really weird question. It's similar to asking why `if (foo) { doBar(); }` works differently than `if (foo) {} doBar();`. Why would you think they'd act the same way?

Comment: @yshavit : http://ideone.com/g7SW9t Please go through this. I have commented the code. Please let me know if i am still not able to make myself clear. I know the difference. I am just not able to understand it in my query :(

Comment: `break` will halt the closest loop, which is the closest `while`, `for` or `do... while` (or `switch`). `if`s don't affect it at all. So, both those `break`s will apply to the `while  ((str = input.readLine()) != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet, the second `break` is inside the outer `if` statement. The outer `while` loop will break only when the outer `if` condition is true.

In the second code snippet, the second `break` follows the outer `if` statement. Whether or not the outer `if` condition is true, the outer `while` loop will break.

Comment: But the input i am using will make the statement if(str.contains("sometext")) true in every case

Comment: http://ideone.com/g7SW9t

Please go through this. I have commented the code. Please let me know if i am still not able to make myself clear

Comment: so every single input line will have `icon-lightbulb`?

Comment: No it will be there only when its mnemonic is found. As you have read the program you must have seen that I am reading a webpage through inputstream. Below is the content i'll be reading. I have been able to acheieve what i was trying to do. It is just that i encountered this difference in behaviour and got curious

<div class="span9" style="float:left;">
                  <i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>   lev(leave)+it+y(.yaar)..you casually leave things without any seriousness 
               </div>

Comment: Well, the outer `while` loop reads line-by-line, and the inner loop which gives you the output executes only when the line with `icon-lightbulb` is found. If you have the `break` outside the `if`, then the outer `while` loop will read the first line, not find the `icon-lightbulb`, encounter the `break`, then quit. So you are not getting any output.

Comment: aha finally...i wonder why such a simple reasoning didn't occur to me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You moved the `break` out of the `if` in the second snippet, so it breaks out of the loop no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

In second code:

```
      }

      } <--- "this is placed wrong"
      break;                     //not giving me the required output
   "} <-- should be present here"
}
```

That is why correct indentation is important. Indent your code while writing code (but not after writing).
Even in your first code indentation is not correct (Uniform size tab missing), it should be like:

```
while ((str = input.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(str.contains("sometext"))
    {// <------
        while(str.contains("some_diff_text")==false)
        {
            if(str.contains("something"))
             break;
            else
             {
                     //my code;
             }
         }
         break;     
     }// <------ if ends 
}
//   1   2   3  uniform tab spaces ...
```

Notice each `}` comes just vertically below `{` in same line (for example I marked for if in comment). Also each line between code block `{...}` start at one more tab spaces then `{` tab spaces.

Comment: Or use an IDE and don't fight its indentation.

Comment: @hexafraction yes! with auto-indent option enable :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : no i am not asking about any compilation error

http://ideone.com/g7SW9t

Please go through this. I have commented the code. Please let me know if i am still not able to make myself clear

Comment: @conondrum let me check

Comment: @conondrum sorry couldn't find error :( .. you can post a new question. But explain your question corrected..well indented.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : Thank you for taking out time to have a look